# d3.event's x and y coordinates are incorrect while showing tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to display a tooltip on the horizontal bar chart. This tooltip does not work properly if I scroll down the page a bit.

This works fine if the bar chart is in view and there is no need to scroll. But if I add more elements above the chart, as I scroll down tooltip goes higher from the mouse pointer.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Here is the code:

```js
//Ignore test data
var birthData = [{
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "January",
    "births": 31502
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "February",
    "births": 26703
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "March",
    "births": 28853
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "April",
    "births": 26958
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "May",
    "births": 28591
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "June",
    "births": 29545
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "July",
    "births": 30086
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "August",
    "births": 30947
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "September",
    "births": 32338
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "October",
    "births": 32296
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "November",
    "births": 30326
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "December",
    "births": 28994
  }
]

//d3 code
var minYear = d3.min(birthData, function(d) {
  return d.year;
});
var maxYear = d3.max(birthData, function(d) {
  return d.year;
});
var width = 600;
var height = 600;
var barPadding = 30;
var numBars = 12;
var barWidth = 10;

var maxBirths = d3.max(birthData, function(d) {
  return d.births;
});

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, maxBirths])
  .range([0, width]);

var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div').classed('tooltip', true);

var g = d3.select('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(birthData.filter(function(d) {
    return d.year === minYear;
  }))
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(40, 40)');

g.append('rect')
  .attr('width', function(d) {
    return xScale(maxBirths);
  })
  .attr('height', barWidth)
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    return (barWidth + barPadding) * i;
  }).attr('fill', 'grey');

g.append('rect')
  .attr('width', function(d) {
    return xScale(d.births);
  })
  .attr('height', barWidth)
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    return (barWidth + barPadding) * i;
  }).attr('fill', 'blue')
  .classed('original', true);

g.append('text')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    return (barWidth + barPadding) * i;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.month;
  });

g.on('mousemove', showToolTip)
  .on('mouseout', hideToolTip)
  .on('touchstart', showToolTip)
  .on('touchend', hideToolTip);


function hideToolTip() {
  tooltip
    .style('opacity', 0);
}

function showToolTip(d) {
  tooltip
    .style('opacity', 1)
    .style('left', d3.event.x + 'px')
    .style('top', d3.event.y + 'px')
    .text(d.month + ': ' + d.births)
};
```

```css
svg,
input {
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  display: block;
}

.tooltip {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 8px solid blue;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>D3 Birth Chart</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div style="height: 200px; width: 200px">
    <h2>Dashboard</h2>
  </div>
  <svg>
  </svg>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `d3.event.x` and `d3.event.y` use `d3.event.pageX` and `d3.event.pageY`. [event.pageX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX):

> returns the X (horizontal) coordinate (in pixels) at which the mouse was clicked, relative to the left edge of the entire document. This includes any portion of the document not currently visible.

The same goes for `pageY`.

Here is your code with that change:

```js
//Ignore test data
var birthData = [{
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "January",
    "births": 31502
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "February",
    "births": 26703
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "March",
    "births": 28853
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "April",
    "births": 26958
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "May",
    "births": 28591
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "June",
    "births": 29545
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "July",
    "births": 30086
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "August",
    "births": 30947
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "September",
    "births": 32338
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "October",
    "births": 32296
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "November",
    "births": 30326
  },
  {
    "year": 1967,
    "month": "December",
    "births": 28994
  }
]

//d3 code
var minYear = d3.min(birthData, function(d) {
  return d.year;
});
var maxYear = d3.max(birthData, function(d) {
  return d.year;
});
var width = 600;
var height = 600;
var barPadding = 30;
var numBars = 12;
var barWidth = 10;

var maxBirths = d3.max(birthData, function(d) {
  return d.births;
});

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, maxBirths])
  .range([0, width]);

var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div').classed('tooltip', true);

var g = d3.select('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(birthData.filter(function(d) {
    return d.year === minYear;
  }))
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(40, 40)');

g.append('rect')
  .attr('width', function(d) {
    return xScale(maxBirths);
  })
  .attr('height', barWidth)
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    return (barWidth + barPadding) * i;
  }).attr('fill', 'grey');

g.append('rect')
  .attr('width', function(d) {
    return xScale(d.births);
  })
  .attr('height', barWidth)
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    return (barWidth + barPadding) * i;
  }).attr('fill', 'blue')
  .classed('original', true);

g.append('text')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    return (barWidth + barPadding) * i;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.month;
  });

g.on('mousemove', showToolTip)
  .on('mouseout', hideToolTip)
  .on('touchstart', showToolTip)
  .on('touchend', hideToolTip);


function hideToolTip() {
  tooltip
    .style('opacity', 0);
}

function showToolTip(d) {
  tooltip
    .style('opacity', 1)
    .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 'px')
    .style('top', d3.event.pageY + 'px')
    .text(d.month + ': ' + d.births)
};
```

```css
svg,
input {
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  display: block;
}

.tooltip {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 8px solid blue;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>D3 Birth Chart</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div style="height: 200px; width: 200px">
    <h2>Dashboard</h2>
  </div>
  <svg>
  </svg>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```